# Weird behaviour of Object.assign

Tags: javascript, object, assignment-operator, spread-syntax

I recently tried some luck with Spread Syntax in JavaScript, where the results were weird and crazy enough to post this question. My assumptions about Spread Syntax is that it is similar to `Object.assign()`, but will it vary with the variables of same nature?

```js
a = {a: "a"};
b = {b: "b"};
c = {c: "c"};
d = {d: {e: "e"}};

d = Object.assign(a, b, c, d);
e = { ...a, ...b, ...c, ...d };

console.log("Before Variable Change");
console.log(d);
console.log(e);

a.a = "s";
b.b = "t";
d.d.e = "f";

console.log("After Variable Change");
console.log(d);
console.log(e);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;}
```

What I have got as a result is:

```
Before Variable Change
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "d": {
    "e": "e"
  }
}
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "d": {
    "e": "e"
  }
}
After Variable Change
{
  "a": "s",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "d": {
    "e": "f"
  }
}
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "d": {
    "e": "f"
  }
}
```

I could understand that `d.e`'s value will always change because of its "object" nature and they are mutable, so accepted. But when I tried using the `...` spread syntax with this, **the first value of the object is changed (`a.a`) but not the second one (`b.b`)**. Am I missing something here?

---

**Extra Info:**

Checked with Browsers:

- Chrome on macOS, Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Chrome on Windows, Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: The spread `...` token is not an operator; it's not part of the Expression grammar.

Comment: @Pointy Okay, I didn't understand that quite right. Can you explain?

Comment: Well "operator" is a term used to describe things like `+`, `/`, etc. The `...` syntax is part of the language of course but it's not one of the operators in the Expression grammar.

Comment: @Pointy Ahhh! Changing it.

Comment: @Pointy Changed. Thanks. `:)`

Comment: you are modifying `a`, vs copying `a`

Comment: @dandavis What about `b`?

Comment: d is a copy of a, b is not, it's just folded into a/copy

Comment: @dandavis _the first value of the object is changed (`a.a`) but not the second one (`b.b`)_ `d.b` stays the same original value.

Comment: right, the first argument to assign is special. if you added an extra preceding var to it, the other values would be the same through both spread and assign, while your first obj/arg would be used to make the output of assign. try calling an assign like `({},a,b,c,d);` to get the same behavior as spread; spread makes a new object, assign modifies an existing object.

Comment: Of course it does. Nothing in your code attempts to change `d.b`.

Comment: You are confused because `d === a` after the `d = Object.assign(a, …)` line

Comment: @Bergi Ahhhhh... Something makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object.assign()` function changes the content of the first object parameter, which is `a`. That's also the return value, so after the first `Object.assign()` call that sets the value of `d`, it'll be true that `d === a`.

Thus the assignment of "s" to `a.a` will also change `d.a` because `d` and `a` reference the same object.

*Just adding my two cents, in a simple way:*

In other words, the spread operator does this:

```
d = Object.assign({}, a, b, c, d);
e = { ...a, ...b, ...c, ...d };
```

Now both the above are same.

Comment: It did change, but your code does not log the value of `b`.

Comment: Where in your code do you make a change to either `a.b` or `d.b`?  You only change `b.b`, and the "b" property of object `b` is unrelated to the "b" property of object `d` (and `a`).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I misunderstood what you misunderstood :)

Comment: Ha ha ha... I got it now... Is it really a confusing thing or is it just me? So now I understand that `Object.assign` and `...` aren't the same.

Comment: `Object.assign({} [,other args/objs here])` is like spread, that's how they vary.

Comment: @dandavis Got it after a long struggle. Thanks mate! `:)`

Comment: @Pointy Can I edit your answer to include what I wanted?

Comment: Sure; I'd probably add something that's not quite right!

Comment: @Pointy Check it out and feel free to update it to make it better. 

Comment: Looks great to me.